# How to change MainPage TextBlock text from UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

In my Main Page I have some TextBlock and UserControl:

```
<Page
  x:Class="MyProject.MainPage">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="" />
    <MyUserControl x:Name = "userControl" />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

How can I get access from userControl class to myTextBlock and change it's text?

Comment: Define a property in the MyUserControl class, then bind the TextBlock's Text property to the UserControl property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, but I decided to use delegates and Events, and did something like this:

In MyUserControl

```
private string myString;
public delegate void MyEventHandler(string a);
public event MyEventHandler MyPropertyChanged;

public MyUserControl()
{
    this.MyPropertyChanged+= new MyEventHandler(HandlePropertyChanging);
}

private void HandleCreditsChanging(string a)
{
    a = myString;
}
```

In MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    myUserControl.MyPropertyChanged += MyUserControl_MyPropertyChanged;
}

private void MyUserControl_MyPropertyChanged(string a)
{
    myTextBlock.Text = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not trying to bind them, there should be a way for your userControl to get access to that TextBlock.
The easiest way can be using a public TextBlock property inside the UserControl and set this property in whether xaml or code behind with the TextBlock.

After than you can easily get TextBlock Text in the property inside your UserControl.

Another option is to use Parnt property of UserControl and try to get all the sibling children there, then picking the desired ones.